# jquery datatables: how to clear column search filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery [datatables](https://datatables.net/) to make my table searchable. I have a dropdown that filters a gender column:

```
$("#genderDrop").on("change", function(e) {
    var gender = $(this).val();

    formTable.column(2).search(gender).draw();
});
```

this works fine, but now I want to be able to remove the filter when the user selects "all" from the dropdown.  Here is my attempt:

```
$("#genderDrop").on("change", function(e) {
    var gender = $(this).val();
    if (gender != "all") {
        formTable.column(2).search(gender).draw();
    } else {
         formTable.column(2).search("").draw();
    }
});
```

Instead of removing the filter this just searches for an empty string, but I can't work out how to change this so it removes the filter.  I also tried:

```
formTable.column(2).search("*").draw();
```

and

```
formTable.column(2).search().draw();
```

but without any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the option All from gender select with empty value:

```
<option value="">All</option>
```

them your code will work:

```
$("#genderDrop").on("change", function(e) {
    var gender = $(this).val();

    formTable.column(2).search(gender).draw();
});
```

Using DataTables example as base: http://jsfiddle.net/PauloSegundo/g15xakh5/

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below:

```js
function fnResetAllFilters() {
  var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
  for (iCol = 0; iCol < oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length; iCol++) {
    oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[iCol].sSearch = '';
  }
  oTable.fnDraw();
}
```

To remove all filters and global filters, please refer to below link:
https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnFilterClear

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```js
var table = $('#tableHere').DataTable().destroy();
table.state.clear();
```